# Volume of a pyramid with a spherical base

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, spherical-trigonometry

Given the attached figure, we are interested in finding the volume of this red pyramid ($ABCV$) with the spherical base. We assume that the Cartesian coordinates of the points $A, B, C, V$ are known and consequently,

$$A = (x_A, y_A, z_A),  B= (x_B, y_B, z_B),  C = (x_C, y_C, z_C), V = (x_V, y_V, z_V)$$

The radius $r$ of the sphere is also assumed to be known.

**Edit**: Since one can easily obtain the plane equation of $ABC$, the desired volume of the red pyramidoid is obtained as: volume of large pyramid $ABCO$ + volume of small pyramid $ABCV$ - volume of the "spherical triangle - like" $ABCO$.

So the new question is: how can we compute the volume of this "spherical pyramidoid" $ABCO$?

Any help would be useful.

[image: pyramid with spherical base]

Comment: @jimjim I have tried to extract the plane equations of $ABV, ACV, BVC$ which is easy but I don't know how to use them (if possible) in order to calculate the desired volume.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Comment: @jimjim No, it's quite different.

Comment: good point, this should do it https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html

Comment: Only the surface (base) is the same as the one of a spherical triangle. It requires different approach. The volume of a spherical triangle is just given by $V= \Omega r^3/3$.

Comment: The base triangle is not a spherical triangle. A spherical triangle consists of arcs of great circles of the sphere. The only plane contining such an arc goes through the centre of the sphere. Your pyramid obviously has slanted planes, and these cut the the sphere more shallowly, so the curved base edge is not a great circle arc. You also haven't specified the height of the pyramid, and while it looks like its straight edges are intended to be tangent to the sphere, you should specify.

Comment: The height of the pyramid is not known, although I suppose it can be calculated (as $\|V\| - r$ ? )

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed that $V$ was given so ignore that bit of my previous comment.

Comment: Some ideas: $V_{ABCV} = V_{ABCVO} - V_{ABCO} = (V_{OABV} + V_{OBCV} + V_{OCAV}) - V_{ABCO}$.
The first three are pyramid with apex $O$ and a planar base (a triangle consists of two straight edges and a concave circular arc). As long as you can figure out the area $\Delta$ of that base and the distance $h$ between the plane and $O$, the volume of these pyramids is $\frac13 h\Delta$. $ABCO$ is a spherical pyramid whose base is a spherical triangle with small circular arcs as edges. It has area $\frac13\Omega r^3$.

Comment: To compute the solid angle $\Omega$, you need to use the version of [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) which involves the geodesic curvature of the small circular arcs.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you very much. It seems that this is the only (hard) way to compute this.

Answer (score 1):

You need not worry about the pyramidoid outside the sphere.

Area of spherical triangle  $ A_{sph\;triangle} $ is found by spherical excess times r^2.

$$( \alpha + \beta + \gamma - \pi) r^2$$

These three are the dihedral angles at the three vertices.The three equitorial planes have three intersections with the sphere as great circles.

The volume of the convex "pyramidoid" is

$$ V= A_{sph\;triangle} \cdot \dfrac{r}{3}$$
It can be found by integrating thin differential shell elements.

Check for pyramid with very small solid angle at vertex $\to 0$

$$  V=(\pi/3+\pi/3+\pi/3-\pi) r^2 \cdot r/3 \to 0 $$

Check for hemisphere

$$  V=(\pi+\pi+\pi-\pi) r^2 \cdot r/3 = \frac23 \pi r^3 $$

Check for full sphere

$$  V=(\pi+\pi+\pi-\pi) r^2 \cdot r/3 = \frac43 \pi r^3 $$

Comment: The volume $V$ represents the volume of a spherical triangle. This is not a spherical triangle as it is not formed by 3 great circular arcs.

Comment: If planes  do not pass through the sphere center we get "small circles". You have *not* defined any intersecting planes.not passing through the sphere center.

Comment: A triangle has no volume.

Comment: The red pyramidoid has a volume as well as the spherical pyramidoid $ABCO$. The point is that I do not think its volume is computed as the volume of a spherical triangle.

Comment: If so, you need to define how the newly formed intersections have come about.